# Vertically centering subtable in cells of a main longtable

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

I am trying to *vertically center* the subtables in the cells of column 2:

[image]

As you can see, the subtable with a1, a2 is vertically top centered. Analogous situation regarding the cell bellow.

I would like to keep the *structure* of table of each cell of column2.

I have tried the following code, but I do not know how to progress:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Your table caption} \label{tab:my_label} \\
    \hline
    header 1 & header 2 & header 3 \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \multirow{3}{*}{row1} & a1 & b1 \\
    & a2 & b2 \\
    & & b3 \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{row2} & a3 & b4 \\
    & a4 & b5 \\
    & & b6 \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `multirow` package is not necessary in this case. You can nest `tabular` environments and easily control between cells alignment, such as top, middle and bottom

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand\TB[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.15}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
  \caption{Your table caption} \label{tab:my_label} \\
  \hline
  header 1  & header 2    & header 3 \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  row1      & \TB{a1\\a2} & \TB{b1\\b2\\b3} \\
  \hline
  row2      & a3          & \TB[t]{b4\\b5} \\
  \hline
  row3      & a4          & \TB[b]{b6\\b7} \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The way you're entering the data in the `longtable` environment, LaTeX "knows" about *individual cells* -- and about shifting some of the down (or up) if they're the argument of a `\multirow` instruction. By default, LaTeX does *not know* that vertically arranged cells sandwiched between `\hline` directives are supposed to form a "sub-table".

If you want to have LaTeX operate on subtables rather than on cells, you need to provide the crucial pieces of information yourself. In the code below, this is done via `subtab` instructions (defined in the preamble of the test document in terms of a `tabular` environment; by default, adjacent `tabular` environments are centered vertically relative to each other). Note that it's not necessary to encase `row1` and `row2` in `\subtab` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}    
\newcommand\subtab[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    header 1 & header 2 & header 3 \\
    \hline
    row1 & \subtab{a1\\a2} & \subtab{b1\\b2\\b3} \\
    \hline
    row2 & \subtab{a3\\a4} & \subtab{b4\\b5\\b6} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```