# Problem with vertical centering of cells of a same row of a longtable

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

This question follows up a previous question: [Vertically centering subtable in cells of a main longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695485/vertically-centering-subtable-in-cells-of-a-main-longtable).

I am using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TB}{O{c} m O{c}}{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#3@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|L{6cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
        \caption{Your table caption} \label{tab:my_label} \\
        \hline
        header 1  & header 2    & header 3 \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \lipsum[1]      & \TB{a1\\a2} & \TB{b1\\b2\\b3} \\
        \hline
        row2      & a3          & \TB[t]{b4\\b5} \\
        \hline
        row3      & a4          & \TB[b]{b6\\b7} \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the cells of the first row are not being vertically centered:

[image]

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you switch the underlying column type of the `L`, `C`, and `R` column types from `p` to `m`. (`m` is mnemonic for "middle", I suppose.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,xparse,lipsum}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TB}{O{c} m O{c}}{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#3@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|L{6cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
        \caption{Your table caption} \label{tab:my_label} \\
        \hline
        header 1  & header 2    & header 3 \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        
        \lipsum[1][1-8] & \TB{a1\\a2} & \TB{b1\\b2\\b3} \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mico: that fixes the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

By use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package, code for MWE is simple and concise:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\small\itshape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Your table caption},
  label = {tab:my_label}
                    ]{hlines, vlines,
                      colspec = {X[m, cmd={\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}] *{2}{Q[c, m]}},
                      rowhead = 1
                      }
header 1    &    header 2   &   header 3        \\
% table body
\lipsum[1]  &   {a1\\a2}    &   {b1\\b2\\b3}    \\
row2        &   a3          &   {b4\\b5}        \\
row3        &   a4          &   {b6\\b7}        \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- As you can see, I took a liberty and a little bit redesign your table that according to my opinion make table more pretied:

  - last two columns has natural width,
  - width of the first column occupy the rest widths of the `\textwidth`.
- Contents in cells are vertical centered by use of the `m` option in the `X` and `Q` columns specifications.
- For more details about `tabularray` package you should consult package documentation which contain concise explanation with a plenty examples. For your problem may be interesting the following:
- beside standard `tabular` aligning `c` (horizontal center), `l`, and `r` introduce `f` (at foot of cell), `h` (at top of cell) and `m` (at middle, vertical centered), which can be also used as options in `Q` and `X` cells (later is known from `tabularx` package)
- for manual breaking cells' contents is introduced simple syntax `{<first line>\\<second line>\\ ... }`
- for multi column and multirow cells are defined `SetCell[c=<number od columns>]{<aligning of contents}  cell content` and `SetCell[r=<number od columns>]{<aligning of contents}  cell content`
- Other useful features are:
- automatic adding *continue* to long table captions on the next pages and `table footmark *continue on next page*
- repeating of rows, which contains column headers, is determined by `rowhead = <number>` instruction in the table preamble.

Comment: For the benefit of readers who are not (yet) familiar with the `tabularray` machinery and syntax, could you point out which code particle(s) specifically assure the vertical centering of the cell/column contents?

Comment: Thanks, @Zarco, for your solution. Currently, I am not familiar with `tabularray`, but I intend to study it. In particular, I do not currently understand your `colorpsec`.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much for note. I would add some more explanation at late evening. Temporary I'm on the way (till to the late of afternoon).