# Subtable is not correctly vertically centered in a longtable

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

This question is a follow up of previous questions: [Problem with vertical centering of cells of a same row of a longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695517/problem-with-vertical-centering-of-cells-of-a-same-row-of-a-longtable) and [Vertically centering subtable in cells of a main longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695485/vertically-centering-subtable-in-cells-of-a-main-longtable).

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,xparse,lipsum}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TB}{O{c} m O{c}}{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#3@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|L{6cm}|L{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
        \caption{Your table caption} \label{tab:my_label} \\
        \hline
        header 1  & header 2    & header 3 \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        
        \lipsum[1][1-8] & \TB{some text, \\ some text\\some text, \\ some text\\a2} & \TB{b1\\b2\\b3} \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

However, the vertical centering is not being produced:

[image]

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing `\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#3@{}}#2\end{tabular}` with `\smash{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#3@{}}#2\end{tabular}}`. Not sure why it works...

Comment: If you change `L`, `C` and `R` column types to `p{}` and then enclose `\lipsum[1][1-8]` within `\TB`, that is `\TB{\lipsum[1][1-8]}[p{\linewidth}]`, you will get the perfect middle alignment. For some reason, sometimes mixing multilined cells, with nested tabulars makes `m{}` incorrect to determine middle points.

Comment: Thanks, @Mico, for your idea. While it fixes the issue in the example I gave you, unfortunately, when one uses `\TB` to have a multine header, the header overflows the row of the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment the following code works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,xparse,lipsum}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TB}{O{c} m O{c}}{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#3@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.15}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|L{6cm}|L{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
  \caption{Your table caption} \label{tab:my_label} \\
  \hline
  header 1  & header 2    & header 3 \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  
  \TB{\lipsum[1][1-8]}[p{\linewidth}]
            & \TB{some text, \\ some text\\some text, \\ some text\\a2}
            & \TB{b1\\b2\\b3} \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

IMO the original code should also work, although I also get incorrect results when I sometimes mix cells with nested `tabular`s. Consider two packages [makecell](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) or [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), which likely make your life easier in these scenarios.

As to the example, it has something to do with determining correct baselines but I don't want to go into details as I am not entirely sure what happens.
The code above works I think because from a parent cell perspective, there is only the middle baseline established by nested tabulars, middle because of the effect of `[c]`. Then, `p{}` lines up all three cells w.r.t baselines and hence you get the perfect middle alignment.

Comment: Thanks, @Celdor: Your approach works perfectly!

Comment: Np.  I am glad it's working for you.